# Panda 0.22 dataframe.drop more rows than it should

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Loaded two dataframes(testdf and datadf) from two files and then used

`df = pd.concat([testdf,datadf])`
produces a df.shape of (48842,15) so far so good.

Now I need 80% train, 10% test, 10% validation

`trndf = df.sample(frac=0.8)`returns a shape of (39074,15) which is correct.

`tmpdf = df.drop(trndf.index)`now the idea here is to remove those 39074 rows from the df dataframe which should leave a total of 9768. However tmpdf dataframe shape is (4514,15) losing 5254 rows.

df uses a default index which is numbered from 0 to 48841 a sample below

`idx  age  work class
  0   25   Private
  1   28   Private`

The trndf dataframe sample below which is random sample and I confirmed the index numbers matched the index in df dataframe

`idx   age  work class
 228   25      ?
2164   35   State-gov`

Open to ideas on how it managed to lose those extra rows. Appreciate any insight on this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `pd.concat` does not reset the indices, and thus if there are indices that exist in both `testdf` and `datadf`, they would both get dropped in the same time when such indices are sampled out.

`drop` will drop all the duplicated indices and thus you lose more rows from the indices that exist both in `testdf` and `datadf`.

**Potential solutions** are changing `df = pd.concat([testdf,datadf])` to

```
df = pd.concat([testdf,datadf]).reset_index()
```

or

```
df = pd.concat([testdf,datadf], ignore_index=True)
```

**Problem Reproduced:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 0.6987303529918656,
  1: -1.4637804486869905,
  2: 0.4512092453413682,
  3: 0.03898323021771516,
  4: -0.143758037238284,
  5: -1.6277278110578157}})

df_combined = pd.concat([df, df])
print(df_combined)
print(df_combined.shape)
sample = df_combined.sample(frac=0.5)
print(sample.shape)
df_combined.drop(sample.index).shape

          a
0  0.698730
1 -1.463780
2  0.451209
3  0.038983
4 -0.143758
5 -1.627728
0  0.698730
1 -1.463780
2  0.451209
3  0.038983
4 -0.143758
5 -1.627728
(12, 1) # print(df_combined.shape)
(6, 1)  # print(sample.shape)
Out[37]:
(4, 1)  # df_combined.drop(sample.index).shape
```

Comment: Thanks so much didn't realize it kept the same indexes. The .reset_index() worked fine.